# xPath element with focusable value on false

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]Dom:
I need to click either on "svg" or "path" element from given DOM. I'm fighting with the problem using slightly everything but all in all it's not possible to find it. I suppose it may be a problem with that: "focusable" value set on false.

I need to create method which goal will be to:
1) Differentiate element from many elements which I would like to delete:
2) Click and delete an element

What I've already tried is first to differentiate an element (filterChip) - it works correctly. Next step is to get an element responsible for clicking ("X" button on UI). Directly on DOM two element may be an option to get it:
- svg
- path

```cs
filterChipLocator -"//div[contains(@class,'chip')]//child::span[contains(text(),'{0}')]";

 public void DeleteFilterChip(string filterInput)
        {
           var filterChip = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format(filterChipLocator, filterInput)));
 var deleteFilterChip = filterChip.FindElement(By.XPath("//parent::div[contains(@class,'chip')]//svg[@role = 'presentation']"));
        }
```

DOM

```
<div class="jss480 jss481 jss520 jss546">
    <div class="jss481" style="line-height: 64px;">
        <div role="button" class="jss656 jss662 chip" tabindex="0" style=""><span class="jss675" style="">Test1</span>
            <svg class="jss358 jss676" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
                <path d="M12 2C6.47 2 2 6.47 2 12s4.47 10 10 10 10-4.47 10-10S17.53 2 12 2zm5 13.59L15.59 17 12 13.41 8.41 17 7 15.59 10.59 12 7 8.41 8.41 7 12 10.59 15.59 7 17 8.41 13.41 12 17 15.59z"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jss481" style="line-height: 64px;">
        <div role="button" class="jss656 jss662 chip" tabindex="0"><span class="jss675">Test2</span>
            <svg class="jss358 jss676" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
                <path d="M12 2C6.47 2 2 6.47 2 12s4.47 10 10 10 10-4.47 10-10S17.53 2 12 2zm5 13.59L15.59 17 12 13.41 8.41 17 7 15.59 10.59 12 7 8.41 8.41 7 12 10.59 15.59 7 17 8.41 13.41 12 17 15.59z"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Becuase of html incorrect indentation I'm uploading also in image:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the `svg` element you need to use

```
//*[name()='svg']
```

OR

```
//*[local-name()='svg']
```

Try the following xpath to access the `svg` elements.

```
//div[contains(@class,'chip')]//*[name()='svg'][@role = 'presentation']
```

OR

```
//div[contains(@class,'chip')]//*[local-name()='svg'][@role = 'presentation']
```

OR

```
 //div[contains(@class,'chip')]//*[name()='svg'][@role = 'presentation']/*[name()='path']
```

Check this link :- How to identify [svg](http://payitforward14.blogspot.com/2015/06/how-to-write-xpath-for-svg-elements.html) element.

Comment: Can you tell me what does it mean: [name()='svg'][@role = 'presentation']?

Comment: As I mentioned to identify the `svg` element in selenium you need to use `//* [name()='svg']` or //*[local-name()='svg']`

Comment: check this link : http://payitforward14.blogspot.com/2015/06/how-to-write-xpath-for-svg-elements.html